# Application Error on Heroku for node and angular application

Tags: angularjs, heroku

I can't see my website with heroku. Why? what's the problem?
My logs are :

> 2017-01-07T09:01:05.406777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
>   2017-01-07T09:01:05.418855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2017-01-07T09:01:06.670282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=3cab0568-3af9-47da-8f98-ed8828db9b3a fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:01:06.872148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=d2af6b74-852d-4edc-b4aa-9575222788ff fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:01:07.301323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=5b02133c-9589-4645-a625-37a4b4f6e4b2 fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:01:07.329927+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=9f4497ae-0288-4cca-ac07-c24a627ba36a fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:01:08.813181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=db394667-435d-4711-8986-9c17984fac08 fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:01:52.416224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=180677b2-c4d8-4af0-84a8-e3ede4af8f52 fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:01:52.783132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=7bd9234b-f394-4efd-934e-907d6e28618f fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:10:35.609452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=02dfd2dc-cb74-4f09-9e87-a08ad9e26758 fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-01-07T09:10:36.216100+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=progettocloud.herokuapp.com request_id=09591202-8bee-4680-8dc9-98c2422a2b6d fwd="151.18.21.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Your app crashed which means that you must have messed something up in your init files.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I try it again ; )

Comment: Did you solve this?